# UITextField crash when selected

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode7-beta3

I am working on Xcode 7 b3 and i created a new UITextfield in the Storyboard.
It is unlinked and not assigned to anything.

When I click it the app crashes. I have no idea why. I can not debug it because it is not linked to anything and normaly should have no reason to crash the app.

Next up I linked it to an IBOutlet and assigned a string. This String shows up but when I tap it the app crashes! No IBAction set.

The error from the console is:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSCFConstantString stringByAppendingString:]: nil argument'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x185f384d0 0x19a9a7f9c 0x185f38418 0x186ddcbcc 0x196c40590 0x18babdb78 0x18babdcc4 0x18bdedcec 0x18bcd1804 0x18bbdb550 0x10028d5f0 0x10028d5b0 0x10029294c 0x185eefa20 0x185eed888 0x185e1d280 0x190f940cc 0x18b60adf8 0x100150958 0x19b1ea8b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Thank you for your help.

reptil1990

[image]

Comment: Clearly you've got some method connected to it - `stringByAppendingString` doesn't call itself. Try reproducing your problem in a new project?

Comment: But how can the UITextField call anything when it is just created. No bindings nothing.

Comment: Sigh well it is a beta  That's why I was suggesting creating it in a new project.

Comment: I would download b4 but the wireless in the hotel is so damn slow -.- but I will try it

Comment: The error youre getting is because youre trying to append a nil string. Find out why that is nil and post the code on here too

Comment: The app crashes only when I select the UITextField. And as you see in the picture it is not linked to anything and trigger no function or is linked to an outlet. Why should it crash?

Answer (score 0):

You are liked had something linked to this UITextfield, and you haven't realise it.

Here's how you do.

`Delete this UITextfield, drag a new one in you storyboard should work`.

If not, I'll help you for the next step